# ggplot2 range of values in heatmap

Tags: r, ggplot2

To plot a range of values in a heatmap geom_point(subset) should work as shown here

[How to draw only a range of values in geom_point from the ggplot2 package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694862/how-to-draw-only-a-range-of-values-in-geom-point-from-the-ggplot2-package)

But I'm trying to use it with this data

```
"people","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"
"Ej1",0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0
"Ej2",0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0
"Ej3",0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1
"Ej4",0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1
"Ej5",1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1
"Ej6",1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0
"Ej7",0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1
"Ej8",0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0
"Ej9",1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1
```

to show the range of values shown in the image. The code so far is this

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(plyr)
data <- read.csv("fruits2.txt", head=TRUE, sep=",")
data$people <- factor(data$people,levels=rev(data$people))
data.m = melt(data)
#data.m <- ddply(data.m, .(variable), transform, rescale = rescale(value))
data.m[,"rescale"]<-rescale(data.m[,"value"],to=c(0,1))
fewer.labels <- c("Ej9","Ej8","Ej7","Ej6","Ej5","Ej4","Ej3","Ej2","Ej1")
p <- ggplot(data.m, aes(variable, people)) +
     geom_tile(aes(fill = rescale), colour = "white") +
     scale_y_discrete(labels=fewer.labels) +
     scale_fill_gradient(low = "red", high = "green") +
     theme(axis.text=element_text(size=8))
```

The code for restricting data should be similar to this one for the "people" exe, but I'm missing something:

```
geom_point(data=subset(people >= "Ej3" & people <= "Ej7"))
```

[image]

Comment: You're trying to subset according to a factor using `>` and `<`. These operations are not useful for factors. You have to either define `people` as an ordered factor using `ordered` instead of `factor`, or you can subset the existing factor by explicitly specifiying which factor levels should be included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like SimonG says, you were sub-setting incorrectly.

```
ggplot(subset(data.m,people %in% c("Ej7","Ej6","Ej5","Ej4","Ej3") & variable %in% c("X5","X6", "X7","X8")), aes(variable, people)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = rescale), colour = "white") +
  #scale_y_discrete(labels=fewer.labels) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "red", high = "green") +
  theme(axis.text=element_text(size=8))
```

Produces this plot, ignoring `scale_y_discrete`.

[image]